# Reverse back to app from safari

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, safari

In my application I am calling an url in safari on a button click,I am using the following code

In safari I am using pay pal payment.Is there any chance to reverse back to my app after donate button click.

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
 if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
     return NO;
 }

  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO That is not possible in case of websites that you dont have control. Instead, you can open the link in your webview.

If you have developed website, you can redirect it to your app using custom URL. For details refer [this tutorial](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

For your case i.e. Paypal, it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:]` method, you can open your website into website inside your viewcontroller, with back button.Thus you can go back into your app from safari..

Follow this snippet,

```
`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:<YOUR_URL>];

 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

 webViewBrowser.delegate = self;

[webViewBrowser loadRequest:request];`
```

Enjoy Programming!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to navigate from Safari to your app, you would need to have control of the web page that you send the user to. Create a button on the webpage that links to the custom URL scheme of your application. Then when the user clicks on the button, your app will open on the device.